# OData can't expand

Tags: c#, odata, expand

I'm trying to use OData and I'm having a problem with using the `$expand` function.

I have 3 entities: Event, Order, Ticket

They are setup like this:
Event:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset End { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new Collection<Order>();
```

Order:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string CustomerHouseNumber { get; set; }

    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    public TransactionStatus Status { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset OrderedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } = new Collection<Ticket>();
```

Ticket:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Order")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
```

If I want to retrieve an Event and expand Orders and then also expand Tickets, there's no issue. As long as I use Event as a starting point.

However, if I select an Order (which is working fine) and want to expand Tickets, I get the following error:

> "'DbQuery`1' cannot be serialized using the ODataMediaTypeFormatter."

Again, this ONLY happens if I want to retrieve the Tickets for a specific Order. If I select the Event and expand from there, everything is working fine.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement 2 things:

1) You should use ODataConventionModelBuilder in combination with MapODataServiceRoute. 
So change your oData configuration into:

```
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
        builder.EntitySet<Ticket>("Tickets");
        builder.EntityType<Ticket>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
        builder.EntityType<Order>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.EntitySet<Event>("Events");
        builder.EntityType<Event>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        IEdmModel model = builder.GetEdmModel();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
```

ODataConventionModelBuilder is used to automatically map classes to an EDM model.

2) Put this into your odata Orders controller:

```
public class OrdersController : ODataBaseController
{
    ODataValidationSettings settings = new ODataValidationSettings()
    {
        AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions
    };

    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Order> options)
    {
        try
        {
            options.Validate(settings);
            return Ok(dbContext.Orders);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

}